# How do I remove a choco version constraint that I previously added?

Tags: python, windows, installation, chocolatey, choco

Previously, I needed a specific version of python and installed
`choco install python --version=3.7.5`

I now want to upgrade, but choco still thinks I have this version dependency and gives me the error:

`Unable to resolve dependency 'python': Unable to resolve dependencies. 'python3 3.12.0' is not compatible with 'python 3.7.5 constraint python3 (= 3.7.5)'.`

Thank you.

I'm using windows 10 if that were to make a difference.

I already did an uninstall of the 3.7.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Chocolatey Python package is a "meta package". It [depends](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python#dependencies) on the [`python3` package](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python3/) and the error explicitly says `python3`.

Try upgrading your `python3` package before upgrading `python`.

```
$ choco upgrade python3
```

Comment: If I do an upgrade it gives the same exact error about 3.12.0 not being compatible with python 3.7.5 and that it's unable to resolve dependencies.

Comment: Check if Python is listed in `choco pin list`. If it is, remove it with `choco pin remove -n python` and then try upgrading. Also which version of Chocolatey are you using?

Comment: It wasn't listed in the `choco pin list`. I additionally tried uninstall python and choco thinks python isn't installed, but if I try to install python it says it's aleady installed. I think I seriously messed up my choco/python somehow.

Comment: I fixed it by deleting the python folder in C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib and installing python again.